# JAVA Get & Set methods with calculations

Tags: java, methods, get, set

new to Java and trying to set up get and set methods. Although one I need to do as calculation based off getSalary() multiplied by getMonths() to get a Year to Date total.

I haven't been able to find out if calculations are possible in get or set methods or I may just be such a newbie I have it in the wrong place.

```
public class Employee_v2
{
    //Instance variables
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private double salary;
    private int months;
    final double increase= 0.25;
    private double year_to_date;

    public Employee_v2()
    {
    //fill in the code to set default values to the instance variables
        first_name="";
        last_name="";
        salary= 0.0;
        months= 0; 
    }

    //Constructor initializing instance variables with arguments
    public Employee_v2(String f, String l, Double sal, int mo)
    {
        first_name = f;
        last_name = l;
        salary = sal;
        months = mo;  
    }

//set arguments     
    public void setFirst(String f)
    {
        first_name = f;
    }   
    public void setLast (String l)
    {
        last_name = l;
    }   
    public void setSalary (double sal)
    {
        salary = sal;
    }  
    public void setMonths (int mo)
    {
        months = mo;
    } 
    public void setYtdSalary ()
    {
        double yearToDateSal;
        yearToDateSal = getSalary() * getMonths();
    }


//get arguments 
    public String getFirst()
    {
        return first_name;
    }

   public String getLast()
    {
        return last_name;
    }

   public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

   public int getMonths()
   {
        return months;
   }

   public double getYtdSalary()
   {
        return yearToDateSal;     
   }


//DISPLAY

   public void displayEmployee()
   {
       //display the name and salary of both Employee objects
       System.out.println("Employee first name: "  + getFirst());
       System.out.println("Employee last name: " + getLast());
       System.out.printf("Employee salary: $%.2f\n", getSalary());

       //complete the code
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");

       //Determine the year to date salary for both employee
       System.out.printf(getFirst() + "'s salary:  $%.2f\n", getSalary());

       // System.out.println(jas.getSalary());
       System.out.printf("Year to date salary: $%.2f\n", getYtdSalary());

       //set and display salary with increase
       setSalary(getSalary()+ getSalary()*increase);
       System.out.printf("New Salary: $%.2f\n", getSalary());

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println();
   }//end method
}//end Class
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: If it compiles it means you can. Exposing set methods and in general mutability is discoraged. As is doing anything other than settting a value in a set method. I don't see the point of having a public "setYtdSalary ()" method, do that in the getter...

Comment: Convention is to name your getters and setters by camel-casing your instance variables. e.g setFirst is wrong (the instance variable should be "first" not first_name). Your IDE can generate the code for your getters & setters

Comment: Stack Overflow is for very specific narrowly-focused Questions. Please state your exact issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque seemed to be specific enough to solve the problem rather quickly. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation are possible in getter and setter.  I would do something like this:

```
public double getYtdSalary(){
   double ytd = 0;
   ytd = months * salary;
   return ytd;     
}
```

Like this you can calculate the year to date on the fly and is always accurate data. For example if you called the setMonths method you would also have to call the setYtdSalary before calling the getYtdSalary.

Also there is no need to call your getters in your class to access your private variables.

I would also suggest using Javadoc comment in your classes as they make it easier to understand what the methods do.

Comment: I would also name your instance variable just "first" instead of "first_name", and I typically set my variables in my setter like so this.first = f;

Comment: One question, I am trying to decipher what you mean by "Also there is no need to call your getters in your class to access your private variables."

Comment: Private means that these variables are only accessible in this class, and so you can access it in the class where it is defined without calling you getters. It is still good practice to get them using your getters especially if you are manipulating the data before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question: yes it is possible to do calculations
this is also needed in many places, as the main reason to use get and set methods is so you can check or manipulate the values before setting them in your class

I guess your Code will Crash on the printing of the year to date Salary, because the variable yearToDateSal is only valid in the Scope of your set Method.

```
public void setYtdSalary ()
{
    double yearToDateSal;
    yearToDateSal = getSalary() * getMonths();
}
```

you should declare your YearToDateSal variable in the beginning of the class, i.e. rigth after

```
final double increase= 0.25;
private double year_to_date;
private double yearToDateSal;
```

and in your setYtdSalary() remove the declaration of yearToDateSal;

this way you should be fine :)

Comment: Make sense, I've only been messing with it for a few weeks. Thanks for the knowledge